# openFile with pandoc 1.13.2 - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, pandoc

sorry for my english in my post (it is my first on this forum, and my question is perhaps stupid).
I encounter a problem in converting a html file to pdf file with pandoc.

Here is my code in the console
`set Path=%Path%;C:\Users\nicolas\AppData\Local\Pandoc`
(redirecting to Pandoc directory)

followed by
`pandoc --data-dir=C:\Users\nicolas\Desktop essai.html -o essai.pdf`

As indicated, my file is in the Desktop, but I got the following error:

`pandoc: essai.html: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

I get the same error if i do (with the file `essai.html` in the same folder as `pandoc.exe`):

`pandoc essai.html -o essai.pdf`

Have you any idea of the cause of my problem? (I precise that the file's name i want to convert is correct).

*Remark*: My original problem was to create a pdf faithful to the beautiful html file generated by Ipython Notebook via pandoc but I encounter the same kind of problem when i want to convert a `.ipynb` file in pdf with `nbconvert`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my problem by adding the full paths to my files (But I have used `wkhtmltopdf` which is simpler to use for a good result.)